# How can I add conda python libraries as ubuntu system root libraries

Tags: dlib, ubuntu-20.04, anaconda3, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import the `scikit` and `dlib` library in my editor. However, it shows module not found. Also, when I try to download the module, it shows that it already exist. I can easily open juptyer notebook via command line.

Even when it asks for password for root permission, it shows:

```
  File "/lib/security/howdy/compare.py", line 17, in <module>
    import dlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
Unknown error: 1
```

However, when I try to install `dlib`, it shows that it is already installed in the anaconda directory.